# Xcode 9 simulator remove frames

Tags: xcode, simulator, frames, xcode9, ui-design

The new simulator comes with the frames that make it look more like a phone in Xcode 9 beta. Is there any way to remove this frames and make it look more like the simulator in Xcode 8?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes there is and it was the first thing I removed. To remove the frames do the following:

1. Click on the simulator
2. Go to Window (top menu)
3. Click on Show Device Bezels (which should have a checkmark on it)

The simulator will now have the same look as the one in Xcode 8.

Comment: What is it about the bezels you don't like?

Comment: @russbishop, late reply but I like when the UI is minimized.

Comment: @russbishop Bezel takes up entirely too much space on the screen.