# How to hide iPhone simulator's device body, device bezels

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

How to show only the screen portion of the iOS simulator, hiding device hardware portion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide iPhone simulator border (non-screen area)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605543/hide-iphone-simulator-border-non-screen-area)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 simulator remove frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385390/xcode-9-simulator-remove-frames)

Answer (score 9):

from simulator menu select window -> uncheck "show device bezels" option .